# Syncing comments between Facebook and Wordpress

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on implementing a two-way sync for a website that started as a Facebook fan page years ago and now is going to be run primarily off site.

Right now here's the process I'm using:

1. Import Posts + Comments from the Graph API. Posts are stored as Wordpress posts, comments are stored as Wordpress comments and some additional data such as Facebook Post ID or Post Author are stored in the post meta.
2. I've created a second submission form (only admin can submit posts from Wordpress site) that uses the Graph API to post directly to the fan page, then run the importer so that when the post is first entered into the database, it already has it's FB_POST_ID attached.
3. Comments from Facebook are easily updated and added to Wordpress. FB-Connect allows Facebook users to login and comment on the Wordpress but those comments are not synced with Facebook as I can't attach a user comment to a Facebook post via the Graph API (I can't control other users).

Has anyone run into anything similar or have other ideas for how I could achieve a "two-way" sync? (Quotes as my current setup is technically one-way that mimics two-way. New posts bypass Wordpress then get synced from Facebook).

Comment: how are you doing the post synchronization? is there a plugin for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit old, but I actually got here from the official [Facebook comments plugin page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) so I'm answering.

There is a plugin called [WP-FB Comments](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-fb-comments/)

It's working fine, you can [read my experience with it](http://giannopoulos.net/2011/07/06/the-wordpressfacebook-game-round-ii/) on my blog
(currently trying out Livefyre so you wont see it in action)

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar 2-way sync project. There isn't a way to sync comments (at least none that I can find). The way this has been accomplished is to create a new Facebook application and thus you comment thru the app, not Facebook's native comments, e.g. [WPbook](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wpbook/). Obviously, it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

[Wordbooker](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordbooker/) is another plugin that can accomplish what you're looking for -- when someone posts on Facebook, the comment is imported into Wordpress, and when someone comments on Wordpress, the comment is exported to the Facebook post too.  The developer is fairly responsive if you have any issues setting it up.